# mongodb to aggregate objects having reference to other objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a number of objects in a collection in which they have relationship with other objects in the same collection. How can i get the complete relationship of one object by simply querying that object only.

**Sample Docs :**

```
{name:'emp1' reportsTo:'emp5'},
{name: 'emp5', reportsTo: 'lead1'}
{name: 'lead1', reportsTo: 'mng1'}
{name:'emp1' reportsTo:'mng1'},
{name:'emp2',reportsTo:'emp5'}
```

If I query the 'emp1', The Expected Result as follows :

```
 {['emp1', 'emp5', 'lead1', 'mng1'], ['emp1', 'mng1']}
```

I have tried an aggregate function as follows :

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([{$match : {'name': 'emp1'}},
    {$reportsTo: reportsTo, $name:name},
    { $group : {
            name: $name
            reportsTo: $reportsTo
    }}  
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking at [$graphLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/index.html) :

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {$match : {name : 'emp1'}},
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "users",
      startWith: "$reportsTo", /** For matched docs from `$match` pick 'reportsTo' field & start connecting it with 'name' in other docs */
      connectFromField: "reportsTo",
      connectToField: "name",
      as: "reportingHierarchy", /** Pushes matched docs to this array */
      maxDepth: 3, /** Search upto 4 levels of reporting structure */
      depthField: "reportingLevel" /** This field explains relation */
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rUAoIaJ2W8I)

Comment: If I add, 2 more documents as below (it’s like multiple subtrees for one of the parent)

{ "name": "Sr.mng1", "reportsTo": "DM" }, { "name": "DM", "reportsTo": "CEO" }

Shall I get all possible paths, as a separate hierarchy? As 'sub-array' or as 'different arrays', in case if same ‘reportingLevel’ occurs, in a hierarchy?

Comment: @MithunS : reportingLevel is a number we’re given and independent to each doc in collection if sr.mng1 has no relationship to mng1 you would not see in emp1 but if mng1 reports to sr.mng1 you’ll get until ceo

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I am getting all the expected docs in the 1st hierarchy as shown in your answer. But I am trying to get it separate like -

[emp1 -> emp5 -> lead1 -> mng1 -> Sr.mng1 -> VP] & [emp1 -> emp5 -> lead1 -> mng1 -> Sr.mng1 -> DM-> CEO], If there is multiple paths in between. Since Sr.mng1, hierarchy goes in two direction here.

Comment: @MithunS : You can not get everything done by MongoDB, you need to offload few things to code for these complex scenarios, So if you check in this query (https://mongoplayground.net/p/WTviP9Q9rNs) You'll see 2 docs for `emp1`, 1st has `DM` & `VP` as `"reportingLevel": NumberLong(3)` cause it started root level as `"reportsTo": "emp5"` & for 2nd doc both `DM` & `VP` as `"reportingLevel": NumberLong(1)` cause root level as `"reportsTo": "mng1"`. So in code for 1st doc you've to write logic to map 'Sr.Mng1'->'DM'->'CEO' & 'Sr.Mng1'->'VP' cause mongo can't do that

Comment: So Is there any advantage, If I redeisign the DB structure like this, by keeping array of 'reportsTo', in case of multiple parents. Will there be any better query, If this is the case? [ { "name": "emp1", "reportsTo": ["emp5", "mng1"] } ] I hope same issue can expect in this case as well and need to handle some part in code. Please confirm.